# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Estoy realizando un CRUD, el cual si muestra los datos pero cuando doy clic en un encabezado ordenar o buscar un registro, me arroja el siguiente error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BY2 asc LIMIT 0,10' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\obtener_registros.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\obtener_registros.php(26): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\crud\obtener_registros.php on line 26

Espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no lo he podido solucionar.

```
<?php

include("conexion.php");
include("funciones.php");

$query = "";
$salida = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ";

if (isset($_POST["search"]["value"])) {
   $query .= 'WHERE nombre LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" ';
   $query .= 'OR apellidos LIKE "%' . $_POST["search"]["value"] . '%" ';
}

if (isset($_POST["order"])) {
    $query .= 'ORDER BY' . $_POST['order']['0']['column'] .' '.$_POST["order"][0]['dir'] . ' ';        
}else{
    $query .= 'ORDER BY id DESC ';
}

if($_POST["length"] != -1){
    $query .= 'LIMIT ' . $_POST["start"] . ','. $_POST["length"];
}

$stmt = $conexion->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
$datos = array();
$filtered_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
foreach($resultado as $fila){
    $imagen = '';
    if($fila["imagen"] != ''){
        $imagen = '<img src="img/' . $fila["imagen"] . '"  class="img-thumbnail" width="50" height="35" />';
    }else{
        $imagen = '';
    }

    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = $fila["id"];
    $sub_array[] = $fila["nombre"];
    $sub_array[] = $fila["apellidos"];
    $sub_array[] = $fila["telefono"];
    $sub_array[] = $fila["email"];
    $sub_array[] = $imagen;
    $sub_array[] = $fila["fecha_creacion"];
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="editar" id="'.$fila["id"].'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs editar">Editar</button>';
    $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="borrar" id="'.$fila["id"].'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs borrar">Borrar</button>';
    $datos[] = $sub_array;
}

$salida = array(
    "draw"               => intval($_POST["draw"]),
    "recordsTotal"       => $filtered_rows,
    "recordsFiltered"    => obtener_todos_registros(),
    "data"               => $datos
);

echo json_encode($salida);
```

Comment: El error parece estar en la manera en la que creas la consulta... que sale si pones `var_dump($query)` antes de hacer `$conexion->prepare($query);`?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Pipe, pero no me sigue arrojando error.

Comment: Pero que arroja el `var_dump`? Esa linea no es la solucion... es una linea de debug para tratar de entender que es lo que está mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que tu problema son dos:

1. El resultado de esta variable es `2`:

```
$_POST['order']['0']['column']
```

y dudo que sea lo que quieres.

2. Estas pegando ese `2` al ORDER BY en esta línea:

```
$query .= 'ORDER BY' . $_POST['order']['0']['column'] .' '.$_POST["order"][0]['dir'] . ' ';
```

porque si te fijas, despues del `ORDER BY` ya cierras el apóstrofe sin dejar espacio.  Deja un espacio y no te dara ese error (quizás otros por el `2` pero ese ya no).  Es decir:

```
$query .= 'ORDER BY ' . $_POST['order']['0']['column'] .' '.$_POST["order"][0]['dir'] . ' ';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, efectivamente fue el espacio en el ORDER BY.